# Eigen vectors of the matrix whose columns are eigen vectors of the original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, orthonormal

Consider a matrix $A$ of dimension $n$X$n$ whose eigen vectors are $y_1,y_2,y_3,...,y_n$ and are linearly independent. What are the properties of the eigen vectors of the matrix $P$ whose columns are $y_1$,$y_2$,$y_3$,....,$y_n$ ?
Of course, we know that $AP=PK$ where $K$ is the diagonal matrix containing the eigen values of $A$. Can we say anything about the linear independence of the eigen vectors of $P$ for its diagonalizability?

Thanks,
Aravind.

Answer (score 0):

$P$ can be *any* invertible matrix.

Let $P\in GL_n(\mathbb{F})$, and call the columns of $P$ $y_1,\ldots,y_n$. Then $\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$, and we can define a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{F}^n\to\mathbb{F}^n$ by $y_i\mapsto\lambda_iy_i$, where $\lambda_i$ are scalars. Represent $T$ by a matrix $A$, and by the above process one can obtain $P$ (among many other matrices).

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more?  The basis vectors are multiplied by $\lambda_i$, So a vector y=$a_1y_1+a_2y_2+....+a_ny_n$ is mapped to 
y=$a_1\lambda_1y_1+....+a_n\lambda_ny_n$. Assume we use the same  basis {$y1$,$y2$,....} for both. So the transformation matrix is going to be a diagonal matrix with $\lambda_i=A_ii$.I understood till this. What are you trying to conclude from this?

Comment: No, we represent the transformation with respect to the standard basis, and obtain a matrix with eigenvectors $y_1,\ldots,y_n$. Since this can be done for any basis $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, any invertible matrix can be obtained this way.

Comment: Hey, I don't understand the solution. Can you explain how to get P?

Comment: Hey, can you explain how you can get P? I still don't understand.